# Python simple neural network code not working

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I'm trying to learn about neural networks and coded a simple back-propagation neural network that uses sigmoid activation functions and random weight initialisation. I was trying multiplication with two input values 3 and 2 in the input layer and target output 6 in output layer. When I execute my code the value for `w1` and `w2` keeps on increasing and doesn't stop at the correct value.

I am new to both Python and neural networks and I'd appreciate assistance.

```
import numpy as np
al0 = 3
bl0 = 2 
import random
w1 =random.random()
w2 =random.random()
b = 0.234
ol1 = 6
def sigm(x,deriv=False):
   if deriv==True:
       return x*(1-x)
   return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
y = sigm(x)
E = 1/2*(ol1 - y)**2
dsig = sigm(x,True)
dyE = y-ol1

for iter in range(10000):
    syn0 = al0*w1
    syn1 = bl0*w2
    x = syn0 + syn1 + b
    dtotal1 = dyE*dsig*al0
    w1 = w1 + 0.01*dtotal1
    dtotal2 = dyE*dsig*bl0
    w2 = w2 + 0.01*dtotal2
w1
w2
```

Comment: It would appear as though you are using `x` before it is assigned.

Comment: And I would expect `w1` and `w2` to continue to increase as it would appear you continually add a positive amount to them in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get your code in order. These lines

```
y = sigm(x)
E = 1/2*(ol1 - y)**2
dsig = sigm(x,True)
dyE = y-ol1
```

need to happen inside the for loop, after `x = syn0 + syn1 + b`.

Next, there are a few neural network items to address. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) is a technical description of backprop.

The derivative of `sigm(x)` is `sigm(x) * (1 - sigm(x))`, or in your case, `y * (1 - y)`, which as you have implemented is `sigm(y,True)`.

Your bias also needs to be updated as well. This is a critical part of the network and is a learned parameter. You could use:

```
dtotalb = dyE*dsig*1
b = b - 0.01*dtotalb
```

The multiply by 1 is unnecessary, but instructive. This is the derivative of the "net" term, which you called `x`, with respect to `b`, i.e. 1.

You may have noticed that the update I gave for b uses a `-` instead of `+`. The very last line of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation#Derivation_for_a_single-layered_network) in the link above shows this is necessary to make sure the updates go in the correct direction to minimize your error.

Finally, consider the possible values your network can output. The final output `y` is the result of calling `sigm(x)`. The values that `y` can take on are in the open interval (0,1). Your network however, is trying to learn the value of 6. The closest it can get is almost 1. So as you continue to iterate, the weights will continue to increase to try and increase the output value of the sigmoid. The weights will grow indefinitely.

With all these changes, try making your target something in (0,1), e.g. 0.6. I am able to get the `E` to decrease to near 0 and your weights to converge when I make all these changes.

**Side note**: In order for your network to learn a value of 6, you would need another layer of weights without an activation function. Alternatively, you could remove the activation function, but then you start to lose the neural network approach you are trying to learn.

Comment: Thanks :) it is working, w1 = 0.19459141500196783, w2 = -0.12292840082904191,  b  = 0.06754766476035066 , y = 0.6000000000000014.. i have on query,  may i know why w2 value in negative

Comment: In general, it is difficult to know why particular weights take on particular values.  The optimization could find many other weight and bias settings which would reduce the error to 0. The random initialization will affect which minimum is found. For your simple problem, `x` needs to be a slightly larger than 0 to get the target of 0.6. Since `w1` and `b` are both positive, `w2` compensates by being negative.